# Passing nD array as a pointer to function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know there's a plenty of threads which are exactly the same but they don't satisfy me. 1d arrays are easy to comprehend. To pass e.g. 2d array to function I use the following solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define R 5
#define C 5
#define RANGE 500



void printArray(int (*)[C]);
void genRandArray(int (*)[C]);

void main(void){
    int arr[R][C];
    genRandArray(arr);
    printArray(arr);
}

void printArray(int (*array)[C]){
    for(int i=0; i<R; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<C; j++){
            printf("Array[%d][%d]/[%p] = %d\n", i, j, (*(array+i)+j), (*(*(array+i)+j)));
        }
    }
}

void genRandArray(int (*array)[C]){
    static int initRand = 0;
    if(!initRand){
        srand(time(NULL));
        initRand = 1;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<R; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<C; j++){
            *(*(array+i)+j)=rand()%RANGE;
        }
    }
}
```

Why I can't use pointer to pointer to int like that:

```
void printArray(int **array){...
void genRandArray(int **array){...
```

I don't know how arrays actually work.
E.g. I initialised statically an array..:

```
int arr[5][5];
```

Then, I know that:

```
arr -> points to very first element of an array,
*arr -> points to first element of the "subarray", where one subarray is one row,

arr equals *arr;
(arr+1) equals *(arr+1);
```

And so on. If I can get the value by *(*(arr+i)+j), why I cannot pass **arr as an argument in function?

(*(arr+1))[3] <=> *(*(arr+1)+3) => why function argument "int (*arr)[C]" is correct and "int **arr" is not?

I aware it's a common issue for newbies but I'd like to get reasonable, satisfying explanation. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Because `int **` is not a 2D array, but - as you already stated - a "pointer to pointer". A pointer is not an array or vice versa.

Comment: @Olaf But if `*arr`, `*(arr+1)`, etc.. points to pointer which points to actual integer in the array, doesn't it make `arr` a pointer to pointer to integer?

Comment: why do people write `(*(*(array+i)+j))` instead of `array[i][j]`

Comment: I repeat: An array is not a pointer, thus `*arr does not "point to a pointer", but "point to an **array**. Read my comment again and read a good C book. You need to get the whole picture, you will not get from asking particular questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your "I know that" section is all wrong. You actually didn't understand a 1-D array correctly and so trying to go to 2-D case didn't work for you.

`int arr[5][5]` is `25` int objects consecutive in memory. There are no pointers.

`arr` and `*arr` are arrays, they do not point. `arr == *arr` and `arr+1 == *(arr+1)` are both type mismatches and fail to compile.

`int **` cannot apply here because `int **` means "points to `int *`", however there are no `int *`s stored in an `int[5][5]`.

`int (*arr)[C]` means "points to `int[5]`".  There is an `int[5]` present in an `int[5][5]`, so you can point to it.

For further reading [C FAQ on arrays and pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/)

Comment: people just won't let all of this "arrays are pointers" nonsense go… :'(